# Radio button selection via tabs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, accessibility

There are 3 accordions on a page with 4-5 radio buttons inside each one of them. All have the same name group. On init the first radio of first accordion is selected already.

When selecting the radio buttons by pressing tabs, the second accordion opens. But on pressing the next tab, it skips the radio buttons and moves on to the next accordion.

This is because the user can select only one option with the same name.

What I want is the second options should be selectable via tabbing, but the name attribute should remain the same. That's the condition-can't be changed because it has a lot of dependencies. How can we achieve this?

I added tabindex values to radios, but no use.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: show your accordian code

Comment: Are **all** the radio buttons grouped, or are they only grouped on the respective accordion pages?  That is, you have 5 radio buttons on the first accordion page and they're all grouped together.  You have 5 radio buttons on the second accordion page.  Are those second radio buttons grouped to the first five or are they their own separate group?  As mentioned above, a code sample would help.

Comment: Also, to select radio buttons, you tab to the group of radio buttons **as a whole** but you change your selection within the radio group using the arrow keys.  You mentioned using tab to change the selection.  That's not right.

Comment: @slugolicious,thats correct,to change the selection within one set of radio groups,we would use the arrow keys.But to make the selection in the second accordion,we would first need  to set focus on the accordion,open it and then again via tabbing get to that selection which would have been possible if it had a different name but it doesnt.

Comment: So let me see if i understand this correctly... You have some radio groups inside of some accordions, and you want to accordion to open up when you tab to it (does it do this yet?) and the want to be able to hit tab again and go to the first radio group offered within that acordeon. Correct? I'll shoot an answer over and start a bounty on this being i found your question solely for starting a bounty for someone else lol :)

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** Here give this a whirl!

This will recognize if an accordion has a tabbable input, not only that but it will open the accordion for you if tabbing through and its not opened but yet has tabable inputs that you wouldn't want your users to miss out on inputing values into.

I hope i was able to guide you i the right direction for this.

```js
$('button').keydown(function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 9) {
    var visibleAccordionInputs = $(this.nextElementSibling).find($(`input[type][tabindex != '-1']:visible`));

    var hiddenAccordionInputs = $(this.nextElementSibling).find($(`input[type][tabindex != '-1']:hidden`));

    if (hiddenAccordionInputs.length) {
      alert('pressed tab on an accordian with tabbable inputs that are not visible, lets open the accordion.');
      $(this.nextElementSibling).show();
    }


    if (visibleAccordionInputs.length) {
      alert('pressed tab on an accordian with visible tabbable inputs')
      visibleAccordionInputs[0].focus();
    }

  }
});

function toggleAccordion(elem) {
  var accordionContent = $(elem.nextElementSibling);

  accordionContent.toggle();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class="w3-container">

  <h2>Accordions</h2>
  <p>An accordion is used to show (and hide) HTML content:</p>

  <button class="w3-btn w3-block w3-black w3-left-align" onClick="toggleAccordion(this)">Open Section 1</button>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <h4>Section 1</h4>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>

  <button class="w3-btn w3-block w3-black w3-left-align" onClick="toggleAccordion(this)">Open Section 2</button>
  <div class="w3-container">
    <h4>Section 2</h4>
    <p>Some text..</p>
    <div class="w3-row">
      <div class="w3-half">
        <input id="milk" class="w3-check" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
        <label>Milk</label>
        <br>
        <input id="sugar" class="w3-check" type="checkbox">
        <label>Sugar</label>
        <br>
        <input id="lemon" class="w3-check" type="checkbox" disabled="">
        <label>Lemon (Disabled)</label>
        <br><br>
      </div>

      <div class="w3-half">
        <input id="male" class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="">
        <label>Male</label>
        <br>
        <input id="female" class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">
        <label>Female</label>
        <br>
        <input id="unknown" class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="gender" value="" disabled="">
        <label>Don't know (Disabled)</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the radios aren't tabbable in your solution? Male gets focus only because its pre-selected, but when you tab again it doesn't go to Female.

Comment: but the question doesn't have jquery tag.